# level of detail expressions cannot contain table calculations or the attr function in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

i have this tableau workbook [image]

basically this calculated day different between each user_id and each transaction for each user_id with this calculation

```
DATEDIFF('day',LOOKUP(MIN([Created At]),-1), MIN([Created At]))
```

that pull filters its so filter the conditions of users (We can ignore this)

and date_rante filters its for calculated day different between date range on parameter

with this calculated

```
lookup(min(([Created At])),0) >= [START_DATE] and 
lookup(min(([Created At])),0) <= [END_DATE]
```

so from the frequency i want to find out the Max of different day, with this calculated

```
MAX({FIXED [User Id]:DATEDIFF('day',LOOKUP(MIN([Created At]),-1), MIN([Created At]))})
```

but it says

```
level of detail expressions cannot contain table calculations or the attr function
```

so i used this solution https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/finding-the-dimension-member-with-the-highest-measure-value

and from that solution, i applied with my codes into like this

```
MAX({FIXED [User Id]:DATEDIFF('day',INT(LOOKUP(MIN([Created At]),-1)), INT(MIN([Created At])))})
```

but it turns to error `datediff being called with string,integer,integer`

based on @Anil solution, i tried to create it, and idk why the results was like this

[image]

new picture

[image]

Comment: Do you want max of datediff values for each user.  In other words do you want what was the maximum time taken by each user for placing their next order?

Comment: yes, the point is, the numbers who appear on that pict was counted and find out where the max number are

Comment: no its not for each users, but all of the users,

Comment: can you show me if the details in your `createdat` field is that date/time type?  If time isn't needed why not change its data type instead to 'date' only?  I think that will solve many of your problems

Comment: I think I have understood your problem, can you please post link of your workbook?

Comment: see it is working fine https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RB1PZrm--x9VdgyX3ceZSO2fpoQYrkr8/view?usp=sharing.  I have edited a few fields of yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently, as far as my knowledge of tableau is, tableau doesn't allow to calculate LOD calcs or further aggregations on table calcs.  To find the transactions where the user took most/max time (in days) in subsequent order- You can do this workaround..

Let's assume your datediff calc field is named as `CF1`. create another calc field lets say `CF2` with following calculation

```
rank_unique([CF1])
```

EDIT:
Change table calcs on this field similar to `CF1`.  putting a filter on this field will give you the dates with max(time diff) as shown in screenshot.

table calculation options on first (datediff field)

[image]

table calculation options on second field (rank_unique)

[image]

I have added third field on colors

[image]

[image]

(Please note no field used in filters just to highlight)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224964/discussion-on-answer-by-anilgoyal-level-of-detail-expressions-cannot-contain-tab).